# How create dynamic themes in WPF applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm just starting to make the transition from vb.net and winforms to c# and WPF and starting on my first app. I've done a lot of tutorials and now it's time to try and put some things into practice.

My first challenge is theming of my application. I want to present my user with a choice of themes which will have preset colour schemes for each control on my forms. For example a Light and Dark mode. I've managed some form theming by putting styling in App.xaml (the app will have multiple forms, so I understand it will need to be here?). Some of it had to be complicated for the drop down main menu (I lifted this code - waaay over my WPF knowldege at the moment):

```xml
    <Application.Resources>
        
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#303030"/>
        </Style> 

        <Style TargetType="Menu">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#202020"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,4"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}">
                                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" 
                                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3"
                                              Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="true"
                                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false"
                                               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                                               Placement="Bottom"
                                               IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}">
                                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" Background="#202020" BorderBrush="#202020" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2">
                                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer"
                                                             Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                        <Canvas Height="0" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                            <Rectangle Name="OpaqueRect" Height="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder, Path=ActualHeight}"
                                                                         Width="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                                         Fill="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuBorder, Path=Background}"/>
                                                        </Canvas>
                                                        <!-- Icon separator color: -->
                                                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1" Margin="29,2,0,2" Fill="#202020"/>
                                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                                                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"
                                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Popup>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Popup" Property="Popup.PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Value="{x:Null}" Property="MenuItem.Icon">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D0767B8" Property="Border.Background"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF0767B8" Property="Border.BorderBrush"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070" Property="TextElement.Foreground"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070" Property="Shape.Fill"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false">
                                        <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer, Path=VerticalOffset}"
                                                Property="Canvas.Top"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset}"
                                                Property="Canvas.Left"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   
    
    
    </Application.Resources>
```

This, of course, sets Styles at compile time, but I need Styles set dynamically and repeatedly at runtime.

However, I'd like to have it so that the user selects a theme from a drop-down in a settings menu and all forms are displayed with the new theme.  Preferably in real time, but "restart required" would be permissible.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Conceptually, it would almost be like swapping in different CSS style sheets.

Comment: "What would be the best way to achieve this" - find ready made solution, there are many of them. ""restart required would be permissible" - wpf allows that out of box

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to reference all relevant resources as `DynamicResource`. This allows the engine to monitor and update the element's resources at runtime.

To make it work, you must define a resource for each themed attribute, like border thickness, font size or colors/brushes. You then register each with an individual static resource key that you define as `ComponentResourceKey`. You use this key in XAML resources instead of the usual `string` literals, for example

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static ButtonBackgroundBrushKey}" />
```

instead of

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundBrush" />.
```

Define each theme in its dedicated file (`ResourceDictionary`). All resources of the different themes that target the same attribute must use the same static key, so that you can swap the actual resources by key.

The following simple example shows two themes. One will make buttons appear rectangular and red (the default theme) while the other will make the buttons rounded and orange.
At the click of a button the rounded theme is loaded to replace the squared theme.
All resource files are located in the project's root folder "Resources":

**ThemingResources.cs**
Define constants to replace `string` literals like resource file names and resource keys.
By defining resource keys as static fields, we also enable the user of our controls to define his own resources in order to replace the predefined ones (control customization).

```cs
public static class ThemingResources
{
  public static readonly Uri SquaredThemeResourcesFileUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Resources/SquaredTheme.xaml");
  public static readonly Uri RoundThemeResourcesFileUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Resources/RoundTheme.xaml");

  public static ComponentResourceKey ButtonBackgroundBrushKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(ThemingResources), "ButtonBackgroundBrushKey");
  public static ComponentResourceKey ButtonBackgroundColorKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(ThemingResources), "ButtonBackgroundColorKey");
  public static ComponentResourceKey ButtonCornerRadiusKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(ThemingResources), "ButtonCornerRadiusKey");
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<!-- The button that switches to the round theme and which is actually themed -->
<Button Content="Switch To The Round Theme"
        Click="LoadRoundTheme_OnClick" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void LoadRoundTheme_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Collection<ResourceDictionary> mergedApplicationDictionaries = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
  for (int resourceIndex = 0; resourceIndex < mergedApplicationDictionaries.Count; resourceIndex++)
  {
    ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = mergedApplicationDictionaries[resourceIndex];

    // Identify the current active theme file (resource dictionary)
    if (resourceDictionary.Source == ThemingResources.SquaredThemeResourcesFileUri)
    {
      // Remove the current active theme file (resource dictionary)...
      mergedApplicationDictionaries.RemoveAt(resourceIndex);

      // ... to replace it with the one for the rounded theme
      var roundThemeDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = ThemingResources.RoundThemeResourcesFileUri };
      mergedApplicationDictionaries.Add(roundThemeDictionary);

      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**
Define all theming resources as application level resources (application scope).

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/Resources/DefaultButtonStyle.xaml" />

    <!-- Merge the default theme (the squared theme) -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.SquaredThemeResourcesFileUri}" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**DefaultButtonStyle.xaml**
The default `Style` for a `Button`. It references all theme related resources using `DynamicResource` and the `static` resource key. This actually enables the `Button` to be themed.
In case you plan to also change the `ControlTemplate` of the control depending on the current active theme, you can reference it as `Dynamicresource` too and define it in each theme file as a resource.

Note, the `Style` is not part of the theme. By referencing theme resources, it actually *applies* the theme.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyProject.Resources"> 
  <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  CornerRadius="{DynamicResource {x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonCornerRadiusKey}}">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**SquaredTheme.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyProject.Resources">
  <Color x:Key="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundColorKey}">Red</Color>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundBrushKey}"
                   Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundColorKey}}" />
  <CornerRadius x:Key="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonCornerRadiusKey}">0</CornerRadius>  
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**RoundTheme.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyProject.Resources">
  <Color x:Key="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundColorKey}">Orange</Color>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundBrushKey}"
                   Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonBackgroundColorKey}}" />
  <CornerRadius x:Key="{x:Static resources:ThemingResources.ButtonCornerRadiusKey}">12</CornerRadius>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Wow - thanks for the answer. It's got me totally baffled - I think I'm maybe reaching a bit too far given I'm at the beginning phases of WPF. I was hoping it was going to be a bit easier than this, given I could just define all global control styles in App.xaml, I was hoping I could just swap these in and out programmatically somehow, but it looks like it's not that simple. Or maybe that's what the above does, in fact! Thanks again for the well crafted answer

Comment: The code is simply swapping in and out a resource file. You only need to define the resource keys as static fields. Evrything is happening in the `LoadRoundTheme_OnClick` method, 4 lines of code. The rest is how you have to structure your resources in order  to enable your application to support the swapping.

Comment: I'm starting to get this conceptually. Did you knock this together in a project? If so - would you mind sharing it? Problem is - I'm taking on a migration to both C# and WPF from WinForms + vb.net and I'm worried trying to implement this blind is going to raise more questions than needed (e.g. where in the project structure does ThemingResources.cs go) - it might be easier just to see it live. If not - don't worry I'll just have to bash it with a hammer....

Comment: You also reference `ThemeResourceKeys` in your ThemingResources class, but this is not showing as a type in my assemblies - am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just created an example for you. It's not from a bigger project. But the example should work. You can try it out in a blank solution to experiment with it in order to understand it better. It's really not difficult once you get he basic idea. Do you know about Styles and Templates in WPF? Also `ThemeResourceKeys` is a leftover. I renamed it to `ThemingResources`. I wrote the code here in the editor without compiler support. That's why I missed it. Replace it with `ThemingResources`, the static class.

Comment: I watched some tutorials on those topics. Thanks. I do appreciate the time you took to write this. Should `ThemeResourceKeys` be `ComponentResourceKey`? i.e.:
`public static ComponentResourceKey ButtonBackgroundBrushKey = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(ComponentResourceKey), "ButtonBackgroundBrushKey");`  ???

Comment: Oh I missed another one, you are right. Thank you. Every `ThemeResourceKeys` must be `ThemingResources`. This is because the static class is named `ThemingResources`. I have renamed the original `ThemeResourceKeys` class  to `ThemingResources`. If you find any `ThemeResourceKeys` then it is an invalid leftover. There only is the `ThemingResources` class. If you have problems to make the example compile let me know. It is supposed to be a fully working example. You would only have to add the required namespaces to the XAML files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245737/discussion-between-stigzler-and-bioniccode).