# Change Color by properties WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, themes

I am working on a theme for my application. But I'm not very knowledgeable about this. My goal is changing colors of controls according to the theme the user chooses.

I store the theme information chosen by the user in Properties.Settings.Default.ThemeName.

I create all colors in the resource dictionary named Color.xaml.

How can I change the colors according to the theme the user chooses?

```
 <!--Theme Dark-->
 <Color x:Key="PanelBackround">Black</Color>
```

For example, how can I change the color of the x:Key `PanelBackground` above? Should I bind properties using ViewModel. Or can this be done directly in the xaml file?

Assuming that `PanelBackround` is a framework element, could there be a solution similar to the one below?

```
   <Style TargetType="PanelBackground">
    <Style.Triggers>
        
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=colorMode}" Value="Black">
            <Setter Property="Color" Value="Black"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=colorMode}" Value="Light">
            <Setter Property="Color" Value="White"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: [How create dynamic themes in WPF applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72676300/3141792)